# Jquery autocomplete plugin Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocompletar

Estoy usando este maravilloso [plugin](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/) desarrollado por Devbridge. Utilizando sus ejemplos uno me funciona bien y el otro no:

El que funciona:

```
// Obtengo listaDeProfesionales desde /profesionales/get_lista/
$('#autocompleteInput').autocomplete({
    lookup: listaDeProfesionales,
});
```

El que **no** funciona:

```
$('#autocompleteInput').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: "/profesionales/get_lista/",
});
```

Me arroja este error en pantalla:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
> ```

En el archivo del plugin

```
jquery.autocomplete-devbridge.js:792
```

No entiendo por qué, ya que es la misma fuente de información, solo que una es almacenada localmente y la otra es vía AJAX. `/profesionales/get_lista/` retorna un JSON en el formato `{value: "..", data: any}` como solicita el plugin.

Según la documentación el parametro serviceURL debe proveer la URL que retorna un string de serviceUrl. Por lo que veo no estoy entendiendo muy bien que se supone que es.

Comment: En ninguno de esos codigos aparece usada la propiedad `length`. Falta codigo relevante que no estás enseñando?

Comment: `/profesionales/get_lista/` que devuelve? un JSON?

Comment: Ahí edité la pregunta respondiendo sus dudas. Gracias!

Comment: un objeto no es un array

Comment: @Franklin'jGil'z no entiendo tu comentario

Comment: Si tiees " var x = {algo: 'algo'}" no puede usar x.lenght, porq x es u objeto, en cambio si usas " var x = [ {algo: 'algo'} ]", ahora si puedes usar x.lenght ya que es un array que indexa objetos

Comment: Ahhh ahora te entendí a la perfección! Gracias por el comentario!

Answer (score 1):

Ahí encontré el problema, al parece el formato del JSON retornado por la función AJAX tiene que ser:

```
{
    suggestions: [
        { "value": "United Arab Emirates", "data": "AE" },
        { "value": "United Kingdom",       "data": "UK" },
        { "value": "United States",        "data": "US" }
    ]
}
```

Y yo no estaba incorporando la clave "suggestions".

Más información [acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36726039/devbridge-jquery-autocomplete-not-working-with-serviceurl)